# google authorized request issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: function (request)
    {
        request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ TOKEN);
        //request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', TOKEN);
        //request.setRequestHeader('X-JavaScript-User-Agent', 'Google APIs Explorer');
    },
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?key='+ API_KEY,
    //url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible',
    //url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/'+ UID +'/people/visible',
    //url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/'+ UID +'/people/visible?key='+ API_KEY,
    data: null,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(result){
      console.log(result);
    }
});
```

In [playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) is 200 OK and [plus.people.list](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.people.list) working great but when it comes to my code what I get is:

```
Object {domain: "usageLimits", reason: "accessNotConfigured", message: "Access Not Configured"}
```

**UPDATE 1:**
According to https://developers.google.com/console/help/?hl=ru#UsingKeys all I need to Authorize is access_token so I removed all APP_KEYs and
According to @SLaks cannot set request headers using JSONP. Instead, I passed the bearer token on the query string but nothing changed, same issue. Anyway, thanks for your help man.

```
$.ajax({
    //url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?access_token='+ TOKEN,
    //url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?access_token='+ encodeURIComponent(TOKEN),
    //url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?token_type=Bearer&access_token='+ TOKEN,
    //url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?token_type=Bearer&access_token='+ encodeURIComponent(TOKEN),
    //url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/'+ UID +'/people/visible?access_token='+ TOKEN,
    //url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/'+ UID +'/people/visible?access_token='+ encodeURIComponent(TOKEN),
    //url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/'+ UID +'/people/visible?token_type=Bearer&access_token='+ TOKEN,
    //url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/'+ UID +'/people/visible?token_type=Bearer&access_token='+ encodeURIComponent(TOKEN),
    data: null,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(resp){console.log(resp);}
});
```

**FIXED!**
After few changes in google apis console issue fixed and I feel dumb. All I had to do is turn on Google+ API in Services and to add domain to Notification Endpoints in API Access(don't think that the second helped but anyway it's working now!).

Comment: You can't set request headers for JSONP.

Comment: Have you enabled the JSON Api in the cloud console ?

Comment: @SLaks how should I set it?

Comment: @karthikr I just enabled Google Cloud Storage JSON API but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set request headers using JSONP.

Instead, you should pass the bearer token on the query string: `"&access_token=" + encodeURIComponent(token)`